# Data structure with string only

Tags: apiblueprint

I'm trying to create a Data Structure

```
# Data Structures

## Incorrect Credentials (string) 
    - `Insufficient privileges.`
```

This is where it will be used:

```
+ Response 401 (application/vnd.api+json)

    Not allowed.

    + Attributes (object)
        + errors (array[Incorrect Credentials])
```

This is what it outputs. I'm trying to replace the "Hello, world!" with "Insufficient privileges.".

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the string to `enum` should solve it. When inheriting from primitive types you can't set a default value.

```
# API
# A [GET /]

+ Response 401 (application/vnd.api+json)

    Not allowed.

    + Attributes (object)
        + errors (array[Incorrect Credentials])


# Data Structures

## Incorrect Credentials (enum)
- Insufficient privileges.
```